# Nested transactions with different transaction managers in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-transactions

I am trying to nest transactions with different transaction managers wherein if the nested transaction fails the outer main transaction needs to rollback as well

```
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "txManager1", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public int doOps() {
         doSuccessfulDatabaseThings();
         doOps2();
    }

    @Transactional(transactionManager = "txManager2", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public int doOps2() {
        //this throws error
    }
```

My spring config file has

```
<bean id="dataSource1" class ="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
...
</bean>

<bean id="txManager1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
</bean>
<!-- txManager2 defined similarly -->
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

However, when `doOps2()` fails, the transaction in `doOps()` doesn't rollback. How to make the rollback work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bold Statement**
You're doing it wrong.

Based on you description,
you want a [ChainedTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/transaction/ChainedTransactionManager.html).

Create a transaction manager for each of your datasources,
then pass the transaction manager to the `ChainedTransactionManager`
constructor.
Name the `ChainedTransactionManager` bean and reference the name in a
`@Transactional` annotation.
I think the property is named "transactionManager".
For example,
`@Transactional(transactionManager = "chainedTransactionManagerBeanName")`

Comment: I probably worded it wrong. I was certainly doing something wrong since I am a newb at spring. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Does the transaction of doOps() commit before doOps2() has finished or does it wait for doOps2() to finish? If it is the former than I think this behavior is correct.

Comment: If you are using a ChainedTransactionManager, then `doOps()` will vote to commit, followed by `doOps2()` voting to commit (if both succeeded), then both will commit.  I don't know the actual ordering of the commits.  The idea is "both succeed or neither succeed", with no implied order (that I know of).

Answer (score 1):

When you are referencing the method inside the same bean, the @Transaction will be ignored. These annotations are only used when referenced via Spring bean management, which will make a proxy:

[https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/05/understanding-transactional-annotation-spring.html#:~:text=At%20a%20high%20level%2C%20when,has%20no%20knowledge%20of%20it](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/05/understanding-transactional-annotation-spring.html#:%7E:text=At%20a%20high%20level%2C%20when,has%20no%20knowledge%20of%20it).

So calling doOps2 doesnt do anything with the @Transactional txmanager2